# how to use genderize.io API with php

Tags: php

I hate to be a dastardly nimrod, but I can't figure out how to use http://genderize.io with PHP. I'm trying to determine the gender of a user when they supply their first name. So I need something like

```
get http://genderize.io?name=$my_user

if($returned_probability > .75)
     // this person is probably $returned_gender
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
// query to send to genderize API
$query = array('name' => $myuser);

// get JSON from API. make sure you prefix the domain with "api."
$rawData = file_get_contents('http://api.genderize.io?' . http_build_query($query));

// parse JSON into object
$parsedData = json_decode($rawData);

// there you go
if ($parsedData->probability > 0.75)
   // do something
```

Comment: $rawData echoes {"name":"peter","gender":"male","probability":"1.00","count":1388} but $parseData does not echo anything.

Comment: Solved with $parseData = ((array) json_decode($rawData)); echo $parseData['name'];

Comment: FYI $parsedData is an object, so you can `var_dump()` it to print the contents rather than `echo`. Or `echo $parsedData->name`. If you want it as an assoc array, you should use `json_decode($rawData, TRUE);` The second parameter of json_decode will return it as an array instead. This is probably a better option than casting it to an array after the value is returned.